# Android onReceive in BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: android, broadcast

I added a receiver to listen when app is installed. But it is not working. Here is my code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <receiver android:enabled="true" 
   android:exported="true"
   android:name="com.bsp.iqtest.reiceiver.IQTestReceiver">
   <intent-filter>

     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
     <data android:scheme="package"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here is my code in MainActivity (launcher activity) , function onCreate.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   IQTestReceiver br = new IQTestReceiver();
   IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
   intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
   intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED);
   intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
   registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
}
```

Here is my code in IQTestReceiver (this class is written in other file)

```
public class IQTestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  public IQTestReceiver() {
  }
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String packageName=intent.getData().getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();
    Log.e("HELLO",packageName);
  }
}
```

I set a breakpoint in onReceive function , but it doesn't run when i debug.

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: Why did you register receiver in activity onCreate? Receiver already registered in manifest.  Maybe review it. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: do you need to get the event of installation of your app? And if so why you need this?

Comment: Ah,we need to push default data(this data is download from url) when app is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **not** receive `PACKAGE_ADDED` or `PACKAGE_REPLACED` for your *own* app, if that is what you're trying.

"Broadcast Action: A new application package has been installed on the device. The data contains the name of the package. **Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast**."

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

set your broadcasrt in manifest like this

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".IQTestReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="check_values"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
```

and send the broadcast like this.....`Intent it1=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
      it1.setAction("check_values");
      it1.putExtra("data_key1",message);
      sendBroadcast(it1);`

and in on receive would be like this....

```
  @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
           data1=intent.getStringExtra("data_key1");
           System.out.println("ffffff11" + data1);
      }
```